# How to make padding between the one item horizantal bars in asp chart

Tags: charts, asp-classic

How to make padding between the one item horizantal bars in asp chart.
Not between different items

every item has two bars , the blue one and the orange ,How to make padding between them

look at this image to understand
[asp chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyDdu.png)

Comment: see this image:    http://i.stack.imgur.com/lyDdu.png

Comment: How are you generating that chart? Is it a plug-in of some sort, or are you using html in creative ways, or what? Please post your code, otherwise we have no hope of helping you.

Comment: if you are using the ASP.NET chart control then you should change the tags for this question, as you have selected Classic ASP (VBScript).